# How to use the same JavaScript Function on Multiple Select elements with different ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these JavaScript functions that I need to use for 4 select elements that each use a unique ID.

1) How can I use these functions to make all 4 select drop downs function right?

Here are the 2 JavaScript functions and 4 html select drop downs for reference.

**1st Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".addToCart").on("click", function () {
        var quant = $("#getquantity");
        console.log(quant.val());
        if (!quant.val()) {
            alert("Select Quantity!");
        } else {
            var productCode = quant.val();
            window.location.href = "url.com/2.php?a=" + productCode + "&d=" + id + "&c=US&durl=" + idname;
        }
    });
});
```

**2nd Script**

```
function select_options() {
    var textBlocks = [
        '<font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$45.00</s></font><br>Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red">$35.00</font>',
        '<font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$45.00</s></font><br><font class="salesprice">Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red-bold">$35.00</font></font>',
        '<font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$90.00</s></font><br><font class="salesprice">Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red-bold">$70.00</font></font>',
        '<font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$180.00</s></font><br><font class="salesprice">Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red-bold">$120.00</font></font>'];

    document.getElementById('getquantity').onchange = function () {
        var ind = document.getElementById('getquantity').selectedIndex;
        document.getElementById('showprice').innerHTML = ' ' + textBlocks[ind];
    }
}
```

**1st Select drop down (uses id="showprice" and id="getquantity")**

```
  <form id='product_qty' name="product_qty">
  <img class="checkout" src="images/lean_green_usEN.jpg" usemap="#lean_green_usEN">
  <map name="lean_green_usEN">
    <area shape="rect" coords="168,140,341,189" class="addToCart">
  </map>
  <span class="showprice" id="showprice"></span>
  <div class="qty"> Qty:
    <select class="getquantity" id="getquantity">
      <option value="" selected="selected">select quantity</option>
      <option value="413">(1) box $35 ea</option>
      <option value="414">(2) boxes $35 ea</option>
      <option value="415">(4) boxes $30 ea</option>
    </select>
  </form>
```

**2nd Select drop down (uses id="showprice2" and id="getquantity2")**

```
    <form id='burn_qty' name="burn_qty">
    <img src="images/burn_control_usEN.jpg" usemap="#burn">
    <map name="burn">
      <area shape="rect" coords="168,140,341,189" class="addToCart">
    </map>
    <span class="showprice" id="showprice2"></span>
    <div class="qty"> Qty:
      <select class="getquantity" id="getquantity2">
        <option value="" selected="selected">select quantity</option>
        <option value="410">(1) box $35 ea</option>
        <option value="405">(2) boxes $35 ea</option>
        <option value="406">(4) boxes $30 ea</option>
      </select>
    </form>
```

**3rd Select drop down (uses id="showprice3" and id="getquantity3")**

```
    <form id='energy_qty' name="energy_qty">
    <img src="images/energy_mind_usEN.jpg" usemap="#energy">
    <map name="energy">
      <area shape="rect" coords="168,140,341,189" class="addToCart">
    </map>
    <span class="showprice" id="showprice3"></span>
    <div class="qty"> Qty:
      <select class="getquantity" id="getquantity3">
        <option value="" selected="selected">select quantity</option>
        <option value="409">(1) box $35 ea</option>
        <option value="407">(2) boxes $35 ea</option>
        <option value="408">(4) boxes $30 ea</option>
      </select>
    </form>
```

**4th Select drop down (uses id="showprice4" and id="getquantity4")**

```
    <form id='lean_qty' name="lean_qty">
    <img src="images/lean_green_usEN.jpg" usemap="#lean">
    <map name="lean">
      <area shape="rect" coords="168,140,341,189" class="addToCart">
    </map>
    <span class="showprice" id="showprice4"></span>
    <div class="qty"> Qty:
      <select class="getquantity" id="getquantity4">
        <option value="" selected="selected">select quantity</option>
        <option value="413">(1) box $35 ea</option>
        <option value="414">(2) boxes $35 ea</option>
        <option value="415">(4) boxes $30 ea</option>
      </select>
    </form>
```

---

**Edit**

Updated code

On my site when I select the drop down the alert pops up. It should only pop up when nothing is selected and the button is clicked.

These are the two references to jquery I'm using.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**Updated Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("form").on("click", ".addToCart", function (e) {
    // e.delegateTarget is the form whose addToCart descendant was clicked
    var quantVal = $(e.delegateTarget).find(".getquantity").val();

    console.log(quantVal);

    if (!quantVal) {
        alert("Select Quantity!");
    } else {
        var productCode = quantVal;
        window.location.href = "customer_appkit2.php?a=" + productCode + "&d=" + id + "&c=US&durl=" + idname;
    }
});

var textBlocks = [
    '<font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$45.00</s></font><br>Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red">$35.00</font>',
    '<font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$45.00</s></font><br><font class="salesprice">Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red-bold">$35.00</font></font>',
    '<font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$90.00</s></font><br><font class="salesprice">Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red-bold">$70.00</font></font>',
    '<font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$180.00</s></font><br><font class="salesprice">Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red-bold">$120.00</font></font>'];

$('form').on('change', '.getquantity', function (e) {
    var ind = this.selectedIndex;
    $(e.delegateTarget).find(".showprice").html(textBlocks[ind]);
});
});
```

**Updated select drop down**

```
<form id='burn_qty' name="burn_qty" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="gadcontainer"> <img src="images/burn_control_usEN.jpg" width="350" height="225" border="0" usemap="#burn">
    <map name="burn">
      <area shape="rect" coords="168,140,341,189" class="addToCart">
    </map>
    <span class="showprice" id="showprice2"><font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$45.00</s></font><br>
    Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red">$35.00</font></span>
    <div class="qty"> Qty:
      <select class="getquantity" id="getquantity2">
        <option value="" selected="selected">select quantity</option>
        <option value="410">(1) box $35 ea</option>
        <option value="405">(2) boxes $35 ea</option>
        <option value="406">(4) boxes $30 ea</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

**Edit**

The edit code above works now because I updated to latest jQuery

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1-beta1.min.js"></script>
```

But now my hightlight effect isn't working.

```
//-->

//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('.getquantity').change(function(){
$('.salesprice').effect("highlight", {},  3000);
})
});//]]>
```

---

**Edit**

I included the highlight effect in the above script as suggested by @JLRishe. Doing that enabled the highlight effect to work normally again. I also updated jQuery and the UI to stable versions.

Here is the updated script

**cdn jQuery and UI**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**Updated Script with included highlight effect**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("form").on("click", ".addToCart", function (e) {
    // e.delegateTarget is the form whose addToCart descendant was clicked
    var quantVal = $(e.delegateTarget).find(".getquantity").val();

    console.log(quantVal);

    if (!quantVal) {
        alert("Select Quantity!");
    } else {
        var productCode = quantVal;
        window.location.href = "url.com/2.php?a=" + productCode + "&d=" + id + "&c=US&durl=" + idname;
    }
});

var textBlocks = [
    '<font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$45.00</s></font><br>Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red">$35.00</font>',
    '<font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$45.00</s></font><br><font class="salesprice">Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red-bold">$35.00</font></font>',
    '<font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$90.00</s></font><br><font class="salesprice">Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red-bold">$70.00</font></font>',
    '<font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$180.00</s></font><br><font class="salesprice">Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red-bold">$120.00</font></font>'];

$('form').on('change', '.getquantity', function (e) {
    var ind = this.selectedIndex;
    $(e.delegateTarget).find(".showprice").html(textBlocks[ind]);

$('.salesprice').effect("highlight", {},  3000);

});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").on("click", ".addToCart", function (e) {
        // e.delegateTarget is the form whose addToCart descendant was clicked
        var quantVal = $(e.delegateTarget).find(".getquantity").val();

        console.log(quantVal);

        if (!quantVal) {
            alert("Select Quantity!");
        } else {
            var productCode = quantVal;
            window.location.href = "url.com/2.php?a=" + productCode + "&d=" + id + "&c=US&durl=" + idname;
        }
    });

    var textBlocks = [
        '<font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$45.00</s></font><br>Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red">$35.00</font>',
        '<font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$45.00</s></font><br><font class="salesprice">Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red-bold">$35.00</font></font>',
        '<font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$90.00</s></font><br><font class="salesprice">Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red-bold">$70.00</font></font>',
        '<font class="font-color-grey">Retail Price: <s>$180.00</s></font><br><font class="salesprice">Sales Price: <font class="font-color-red-bold">$120.00</font></font>'];

    $('form').on('change', '.getquantity', function (e) {
        var ind = this.selectedIndex;
        $(e.delegateTarget).find(".showprice").html(textBlocks[ind]);

        $('.salesprice').effect("highlight", {},  3000);
    });
});
```

Working fiddle (a bit modified to work in JSFiddle without your images):

http://jsfiddle.net/DDNLe/3/

I should point out that all of your forms have unclosed `div` elements, and I would recommend closing your `img` and `area` tags, though that's not strictly necessary in HTML.

Comment: sorry about the unclosed divs etc. I modified it before posting it here. I re worked the code you just gave me because the one you gave me triggered when form was clicked. I needed it to trigger when the image map is clicked and nothing has been selected first.

Comment: I added the updated code in edit in my original post. I'll check your js fiddle.

Comment: Are you sure you copied my code correctly? The second argument to the `on()` method is a vital piece here. It shouldn't trigger when the form is clicked (and it doesn't in the fiddle I provided).

Comment: I will double check in the morning. just saw your js fiddle and everything is performing as should. I'll implement this in the AM and follow up then. I do appreciate your assistance on this. I'm in the learning stage :)

Comment: yes implemented just now using your code and it is doing the same thing. The alert pops up as soon as I try to select something in the drop down.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add your latest code? I can have a look at it.

Comment: @Mike I can have a look a little later, but I recommend using a newer version of jQuery. 1.5.2 is extremely old.

Comment: ok that was the issue. I updated to http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1-beta1.min.js and now it works. But now my highlight effect stopped working. I'll post that code in the edit above too.

Comment: @Mike It's probably some side-effect of having two different change handlers for `.getquantity`. There may not be any guarantee that they'll run in a particuular order. I recommend adding the highlight code to the handler we've already been dealing with. See my modified code above and modified fiddle. That fiddle has jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery UI 1.9.2. I recommend you avoid using beta versions of the libraries with your code unless there's a specific reason to use them.

Comment: adding the highlight effect to the handler did the trick. And I updated to jquery-1.11.0.min.js and to 1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js. Will post my updated code in my edit above. Thanks for your help. One last question: Should I put the jquery code base in my head or just before the closing body tag?

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm talking about the references to the jQuery cdn script files. //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js

Comment: Unless you are experiencing problems with the page loading too slowly, I think the `<head>` of the page is the preferred place to put your `<script>` tags, including the ones referencing the jQuery/jQuery UI libraries. Those should also be placed before any of your own code that utilizes jQuery.